# How to convert m file to c file

Tags: matlab

I have .m file and I really need to convert it to c language. is there any compiler available to do so?
I do really appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of is using [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/), which is a quite expensive.

If you do not want to spend that money, I fear your best option is to recode the m-file in C. Does it really have to be C or might C++ be enough. Using the [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library, Matlab code neatly transforms to C++ without to much trouble.

Comment: MATLAB Compiler does not convert MATLAB code to C code. It archives and encrypts your MATLAB code, and executes it against the redistributable MATLAB Compiler Runtime. A separate and different product MATLAB Coder will convert a subset of the MATLAB language to C code.

Comment: @Sam: Thank you. You're of course correct. It's not the first time I mixed those two up. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Simulink Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink-coder/index.html), from Mathworks, but you must purchase it. You can get a trial version for free, though.

See [this  similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731671/converting-matlab-to-c) for more details.

Comment: Simulink Coder converts Simulink models to C code. To convert a subset of the MATLAB language to C code, MATLAB Coder can be used.